# realloc() invalid old size on struct arrays

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, c99, realloc

I have been assigned to make a functioning student election program for our school defense (and probably for actual use ... ). However I've been stuck with a problem for a while now.

My goal is to make a flexible array of structs, since I can't use an arbitrary limitation, also arrays have a 99-item limit for me (*see end of the post). I have used realloc() but it gives an abort() for invalid old size. BUT, I have tried testing a dynamic struct array in another program and it worked flawlessly. I can't figure out what's causing the other one to crash.

My election program (i.e. the crashing one):

*NOTE: entr_cmd function just moves the cursor to the bottom of the screen and prints a text, and STREQL just see if two string matches, just a shortcut macro for strcmp*

```
struct candidate {
    long lrn;
    char *name;
    int grade;
    char *section;
    char *party;
    char *position;
}
**candidates,
// :: Temporary Array for storing all the candidates in the position to be voted in
**candidates_cur;
int can_c = 0;

[...]

int main() {
[...]
    candidates = malloc(2 * sizeof(struct candidate *));
[...]
            if(STREQL(command, "c")) {
                        struct candidate *c;

                        if(can_c > 1) {
                            struct candidate **tmp;
                            tmp = (struct candidate**) realloc(candidates, (1 + can_c) * sizeof(struct candidate *));

                            if(tmp != NULL) candidates = tmp;
                        }

                        candidates[can_c - 1] = malloc(sizeof(struct candidate *));
                        c = candidates[can_c - 1];

                        entr_cmd("Candidate's Name: ");
                        // :: This recieves the input but replaced for testing
                        c->name = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
                        strcpy(c->name, "XXX");

                        can_c++;
            }
[...]
```

The test program that works flawlessly:

*this generates a random string of numbers for the members of the test struct*

```
struct test {
    char *name;
    char *another;
    int test;
} **arr;

int main() {
    int r1;

    arr = malloc(2 * sizeof(struct test *));

    r1 = rand() % 45;
    for(int i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
        int r2 = rand() % 22;

        if(i > 2) {
            struct test **data;
            data = (struct test**) realloc(arr, (2 + i) * sizeof(struct test*));

            if(data != NULL) {
                arr = data;
            }
        }

        arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct test *));
        struct test *t = arr[i];
        t->name = malloc(r2 * sizeof(char));
        t->another = malloc(r2 * sizeof(char));
        t->test = r2;

        for(int ii = 0; ii < r2; ii++) {
            t->name[ii] = (char) (rand() % 9) + '0';
            t->another[ii] = (char) (rand() % 9) + '0';
        }

        printf("====[%u]====\n%s\n%s\n%u\n", i, arr[i] -> name, arr[i] -> another, arr[i] -> test);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
        free(arr[i]->name);
        free(arr[i]->another);
        free(arr[i]);
    }

    free(arr);
    getch();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as our teacher had put great expectation upon me and told me this was going to be easy **easy** but it's proving itself to be the opposite.

Thank you for reading and have a nice day!!!

*extra non-sense: I'm in a course where we use TurboC++ regularly for programming, but it's pretty hard to do it there, so I instead used C99 with my neovim setup so I can have fast navigation and also most of the things in C99 can work in TurboC++. In other words, I can't really work with (recent standard) C++, if so, I think I would have probably done this more easily*

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory, it will tell you where.

Comment: Having `int can_c = 0;` followed by `candidates[can_c - 1]` makes me very wary.

Comment: I'm sorry if my code is not pretty right now, I'm more concerned with fixing this thing since the deadline is just around the corner. @dbush, I'm will try to do that, is there any tips you could offer?

Comment: @JulianoDavidHilario If you run your program as `myprog arg1 arg2 ...` then you run it under valgrind as `valgrind myprog arg1 arg2 ...`.  The output includes things like reading uninitialized memory, reading/writing outside the bounds of malloc'ed memory, and memory leaks.

Comment: My comment isn't about being pretty, it's about undefined behavior. If `can_c` is equal to `0`, then `can_c - 1` will be `-1`. And while that can sometimes be a valid index, in your case it's *not* a valid index.

Comment: Oooh! I see! I see! Thank you!

Comment: @dbush, I've succesfully logged my program, I don't really know what to do much with the info, would it be appropriate to post it here?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude WOAH! I fixed it! Thank you!!! It was because my malloc is out of bounds XD. it was -1

Comment: Fine! Now that you are familiar with valgrind, go fix the program that works "flawlessly". `:)`

Comment: Review `candidates[can_c - 1] = malloc(sizeof(struct candidate *));`  Consider `candidates[can_c - 1] = malloc(sizeof *(candidates[can_c - 1]));`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry! I have fixed it already though, is still there a need for that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to memory allocation at all! The problem occurs because I keep allocating candidates[-1], i had put `candidates[can_c - 1]` to `candidates[can_c]` memory.

Thank you for everyone who helped! (and @someprogrammerdude for pointing it out)